# Why do the data-price values of my alternative select options not get summed when performing this function?

Tags: html, jquery, function

BACKGROUND

I am trying to get the values of these inputs totalled up, dependent upon which radio button is selected at the beginning. Each radio button gives a number of different select inputs, each with their own data-price value.

When a radio button is selected, the divs for the other radio buttons disappear, leaving only the corresponding radio button div.

There are also some checkboxes which can be selected, but a helpful commenter already assisted me with those.

THE PROBLEM

The selected radio button and it's and visible div include the select input type, and this is where i am having issues.

I can't get the option data-price values to sum when selecting anything other than the first radio button selection and it's corresponding select input.

For example, when selecting radio button DJ and one of it's select options, only the data-price of the radio button is shown.

I need the select option to be added to the chosen radio button, and also for the sum to return to zero whenever a different radio button is clicked.

I'm finding this part really very tricky, any pointers in the right direction would be truly wonderful.
Thank you.

HTML

```
  <div class="wrapper" id="go">
                 <h3>I want a :</h3> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="one" data-price="1600">Live Band</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="two" data-price="750">DJ</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="three" data-price="700">Acoustic</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="four" data-price="350">Classicals</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="five" data-price="800">Indigenous Performance</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="six" data-price="1200">World Music Band</label>
        
       
        
    </div>
    
     <br>
    <br>
 
        <div class="box one"><h2>What’s included with a live band   &nbsp;&nbsp;  From $1600</h2>
        
       <select name="band-options" id="live-band-options" class="type">
            
            <option value="">-Please choose one of these options-</option>
            <option value="guitar-bass-drums" data-price="0">3-Guitar, Bass/Double Bass and Drums</option>
            <option value="singer" data-price="0">3- Singer and Guitar/Keys and Drums/Double Bass </option>
            <option value="add-sax-or-singer" data-price="400">4-Add Saxophone/Singer (+$400)</option>
            <option value="add-sax-and-singer" data-price="800">5-Add Saxophone and Singer (+$800)</option>
            
        </select>
    </div>
   
    <div class="box two"><h2>What’s included with our party magic DJ &nbsp;&nbsp; From $750 </h2>
       
       <label for="dj-options"></label><select name="dj" id="dj-select" class="type">
           <option value="">-Please choose one of these options</option>
           <option value="DJ" data-price="0">DJ</option>
           <option value="sax-or-string" data-price="500">2-Sax or Strings (+$500)</option>
           <option value="sax-and-string" data-price="1000">3-Sax and Strings(+$1000)</option>
       
           
       </select>       
  
    </div>
 
    <div class="box three"><h2>What's included with our Acoustic performances &nbsp;&nbsp; From $700</h2>
     <label for="acoustic-options"></label><select name="acoustic" id="acoustic-select" class="type">
           <option value="">-Please choose one of these options-</option>
           <option value="solo-guitar-or-singer" data-price="0">Solo Guitar/Singer</option>
           <option value="solo-piano-or-singer" data-price="0">Solo Piano/Singer</option>
           <option value="acoustic-duo" data-price="500">Duo(+$500)</option>
      </select>    
    </div>  

 <div id="checker">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="add-ons" id="add-dj" data-price="750">
      <label for="scales">Add a DJ ($750) &nbsp;&nbsp; Mix it up with a DJ to see out the evening</label>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="add-ons" id="add-acoustic-wedding-music" data-price="450">
      <label for="add-dj">Add Acousitc Weddding Music ($450) &nbsp;&nbsp;  Add a delightful singer and guitarist to your ceremony</label>
    </div>
</div>


 <div id="result" class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper  input[type="radio"] {
  opacity:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:0;
}


.wrapper label{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:10px 20px;
    font-family:sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    border:2px solid #444;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.wrapper label input[type="radio"]:checked + {
  background-color:black;
  border-color: green;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').click (function(){
           
            var x = $(this).attr("value");
            var y =$("."+ x);
            $(".box").not(x).hide();
            $(y).show();
        
            });
    });
        
       $(document).ready(function(){
             function validate() {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += +$('#go input:checked').data('price') || 0;
    sum += +$('.type option:selected').data('price') || 0;
    
        $('#checker input:checked').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).data('price')
    })

    $('#result').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
  }
  validate();

  $('#go input, .type, #checker input').on('change', function() {
    validate();
        });
         
    });
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not clearing selections when you switch the top-level radio buttons, so you're leaving selected items from the prior set of selections.

Note that `.hide()` does NOT remove the items from the DOM.  It toggles the visibility, but the elements are still present.  And if they're selected, they will be tallied (if not cleared).

Respectfully, your code and UI need substantial work to be readable (it's very difficult to understand how this should even behave).  But I think the key is this when you select a new top-level item:

```
$('.type option:selected').removeAttr("selected"); //clear dropdowns
```

You can see some mods that I made to your code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/012hpq6e/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the fix Marc, will give that a go now. Just another quick question if you don’t mind, what do you mean by it needs work to be readable? The code is messy and could be simpler? Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Hi Marc, bad news it still doesn't work! The selected dropdown from a previous radio button selection are still carried over...  As i'm sure you can tell i am new to this and appreciate any help i can get!